# CiviCRM not recognizing csv file when uploading

Tags: import

CiviCRM is suddenly not recognizing upload file as a csv file.  It's now giving an error message that csv file not recognized. What is the problem and how can I overcome it?

Comment: could you provide the specific error message you get when you try to upload? My first guess is that your .csv file might have some problems. Try to open it from Excel and see if Excel finds any errors.

Comment: also may be duplicate of http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4630/problem-importing-csv-contacts - not sure which is the better question yet ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at the size of the csv, how big is it.
The number of records in the csv, if it is very big I'd break it up.
Look for extra blank lines that should not be there, i.e. clean it up.
Then what kind of csv are you using, open and save again as csv.
I've had these kind of issues, hopefully this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

encoding matters, civicrm only accepts UTF-8, better change them on a notepad before importing

Open *yourrfile*.csv in Notepad> Save As .csv (change encoding to UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

I often find that saving a csv, then editing it and resaving it will cause problems on upload. hence the workaround is to copy all the data and paste in to a new csv and save and upload. Any help?